# How to stick views to each other

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-edittext, android-view

I have a layout file that has a lot of views inside a LinearLayout. And there I want to add a ListView stuck to an EditText without moving other views. I have used the addView property but it adds the ListView to the bottom of the page ?

(I need something like autocomplete EditText).
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @S.L. Barth Thanks for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this: [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: yes but a custom AutoCompleteTextView that displays my custom values

Comment: I'm guessing as to what your end goal is, but it sounds like what you want to do is subclass `ArrayAdapter<T>` and override `getView` to display the information using your own layout.  If you need to change the data in the list of potential completions, call something like `add` or `remove` on the adapter and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`